# Why substituting the search part in INSERTION SORT doesnt yield a running time of $\Theta(nlgn)$

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, efficiency

$$
\Theta - Tight \ asymptotic \ bound
$$

If we change lines $5-7$ in Insertion sort

[image]

With BINARY-SEARCH(A,p,r,v)

[image]

Why don't we get a running time of $\Theta(n\lg n)$ as we go through the array $\Theta(n)$ and then do a binary search $\Theta(\lg n)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to shift $O(n)$ elements to make room for the newly inserted element even if you find the correct position in $O(\log n)$.